# Delphi hangup when I try to set TClientDataSet.Active to true

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I am following a the tutorial [Delphi Labs: DataSnap XE - Multitier Database Application](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41189). It is straight forward and I choose to use only **http** instead of **tcp**. In the client application I set **sqlconnection.connected** to true without any problem and I set the *provider name* of the client dataset component. But when I try to set **active** to true of the `TClientDataSet` I get the whole Delphi XE8 IDE hangup until I close the server, what is the problem ?

Comment: Check your FireWall settings to make sure that both your server and your client aren't being blocked.

Comment: @SilverWarior I disabled my firewall still get the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem the table is more than 50K records

> the PacketRecords is automatically set to -1, meaning that a single
>   packet should contain all records in the dataset.

When I set it to something like 50 I was able to open the clientdataset instantly

Comment: So I guess that DBGrid caused the entire Delphi to apear as being hanged becouse it was trying to show all those records at once. Guys at Embarcadero should realy change the implementation od Form designer. No component should cause the whole IDE to hand no matter how bad it is designed. So it might not be a bad idea to report this to Embarcadero.

Comment: Be sure that your users really wants to see 50000 data rows at the same time :)

Comment: @SilverWarior or at least not set PacketRecords = -1 by default !!